# INSERT + SELECT : Inserting X entries depending on an IN result

Tags: mysql, select, insert

First of all, sorry for this topic title, I couldn't manage to find another more relevant, so feel free to modify it if you have any better idea.

My case is that I have two tables, one with many colums including one column `Value`, and the second is composed of three columns :

```
mysql> describe s_attrib;
+-------------+-------------+------+
| Field       | Type        | Null |
+-------------+-------------+------+
| Login       | varchar(32) | NO   |
| Type        | enum        | NO   |
| Value       | varchar(64) | NO   |
+-------------+-------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from s_attrib LIMIT 0,4;

+----------+-----------+---------+
|Login     | Type      | Value   |
+----------+-----------+---------+
| login_1  | exception | value_1 |
| login_1  | exception | value_2 |
| login_2  | exception | value_3 |
| login_3  | exception | value_4 |
+--------------------------------+
```

In this table, value is unique. A login can have many values, but a value can't have more than on Login attached.

What I've done to retrieve the values I need to insert for a specific Login ni the s_attrib table is :

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT Value FROM my_table WHERE SOME_BUSINESS_CONDITIONS_HERE;
+---------+
| Value   |
+---------+
| value_5 |
| value_6 |
| value_7 |
| value_8 |
+---------+
```

I know that those values are not present in my `s_attrib` table, so there won't be any conflit during the insertion.

What i'm trying to do, with a single MySQL request is to insert thoses values LIKE that :

```
INSERT INTO s_attrib (Login, type, value) VALUES ('MyLogin', 'except', 'value_5');
INSERT INTO s_attrib (Login, type, value) VALUES ('MyLogin', 'except', 'value_6');
INSERT INTO s_attrib (Login, type, value) VALUES ('MyLogin', 'except', 'value_7');
INSERT INTO s_attrib (Login, type, value) VALUES ('MyLogin', 'except', 'value_8');
```

Is there a way to do it with a single query using a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO s_attrib
SELECT DISTINCT 
   'MyLogin' AS `Login`,
   'exception' AS `Type`,
   Value AS `Value`
FROM my_table 
WHERE SOME_BUSINESS_CONDITIONS_HERE;
```

Comment: As siply as ****. Thanks, I tried somethind a bit different that didn't work, but this one did the job !